# When I request a python requests post, I'm wondering what PHP needs to do to get it

Tags: php

-python code-

```
import requests
params = {'key1':'value1','key2':'value2'}
r = requests.post('https://localhost/test.php',data=params)
r.status_code
```

return 200

I'm wondering what I need to do in test.php to get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following PHP code as a starter:

```
<?php

$key1 = $_POST['key1'];
$key2 = $_POST['key2'];

//for example check if key1 equals to to key2 

if ($key1 == $key2) {
    echo '200'; 
}else{
    echo 'not equal'; 
}
```

This is just a simple example of what you can do but for more information check
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_get_post.htm

Take Care.

Comment: That code makes sense, but the result is strange. If what I'm thinking is correct, params = {'key1':'value1'} If you enter the dictionary's key value in the $_POST value of the PHP temporarily, the value should come out in the form of echo, but it doesn't get any null value. I don't think requests.post() failed to send data, do you have any feedback on this?